# Quotient of polynomial ring in two variables is a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

> With $K$ a field and $K[x,y]$ the polynomial ring over it in two variables, the quotient ring of it over the ideal generated by $1-xy$ is a PID.

I've tried using Noetherianess but haven't gotten further than showing it's a UFD.

Answer (score 1):

It is proved in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/281255/) that $K[X,Y]/(XY-1)\simeq K[X,X^{-1}]$ which is a ring of fractions of $K[X]$, so a PID.